# To show $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n^{\alpha}(1+nx^{2})}$ converges uniformly

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

Show that

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x}{n^{\alpha}(1+nx^{2})}$ converges uniformly on each bounded interval in $R$ provided that $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$. Is the convergence uniform on $R$?

I am working on the above problem. Do I need to apply Weierstrass M-test here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{x}{n^\alpha (1+nx^2)}$.  Then, using the AM-GM inequality, we see that

$$|f_n(x)|\le \frac{1}{2n^{\alpha +1/2}}$$

Since $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2n^{\alpha+1/2}}$ converges for all $\alpha>1/2$, the Weierstrass M-test guarantees that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$ converges uniformly for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Thanks. How did you come up with $\frac{1}{2n^{\alpha+1/2}}$?

Comment: @score324 You're welcome.  My pleasure. From the AM-GM inequality, $1+nx^2\ge 2\sqrt{nx^2}=2n^{1/2}|x|$.

Comment: I have gotten the same result by using the first derivative to find the local maxima.